# For Selenium-Webdriver Headless on Ruby, which browser has the least overhead?

Tags: ruby, performance, selenium, webdriver, headless

I am trying to decide which headless browser to use for web scraping in the background on my Windows machine with Selenium-Webdriver.  I believe the only options available are Firefox, Chrome, and IE (besides HTMLUnit which I believe requires Selenium server, which I know nothing about).  I am just trying to figure out which of these headlessly-emulated browsers will use the lease amount of resources (particularly CPU resources) on my Windows machine.  Any help is appreciated.  Please assume I'm not a programming expert.  Thank you.

Comment: Another supported option is [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/headless-testing.html), which actually is headless. Unfortunately I do not have any performance metrics.

Answer (score 0):

I use Ruby, and I tried using Mechanize with PhantomJS and found my CPU time on phantomjs.exe going through the roof, and also taking a very long time.

I was mainly looking for a way to keep anything from popping up when browsing JS sites.  The solution I eventually adopted for Windows was to run my scripts as a user other than the current user, through Task Manager.  When I do this nothing pops up, and it seems like I'm using less resources as well (than if the browser launched under my user session).